# Trying to dual boot ubuntu 11.04 and windows 7. No OS detected

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot

I'm trying to dual boot ubuntu 11.04 with windows 7. In the installer, there's supposed to be a "run alongside something else" option for dual booting. However, it says that no operating system are detected. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You need to have a bootloader (grub or something else)

Comment: please give more details--what were the steps you took to install the first OS, then the second OS.

Comment: Okay. This computer came with windows 7 on it. I downloaded ubuntu 11.04 onto a DVD-RW. I boot the computer from the DVD to start the ubuntu install process.

Comment: Is it booting from the right device? May be an idea to check in BIOS

Comment: try this--run ubuntu live cd (not install). Run GParted. Post what you find in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply install Ubuntu 11.04 from Windows using [Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer), no need to boot from the disc.